# Invalid Corpora

Tags: oracle, vb.net, plsql

Currently, I have on-prem vb.net application which connects to on-prem database with Oracle 11g.

I need my on-prem vb.net application to connect to AWS database with Oracle 19c. I have updated my connection strings in app.config, but getting error message - **ORA-20016:Invalid Corpora when I call stored procedure.
**

```
Dim dbCommand As DbCommand
dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("procedurename")
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "piv_userid",  DbType.String, strUserID)
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "piv_userpwd", DbType.String, strPassword)
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "piv_appstub", DbType.String, My.Application.Info.ProductName)

db.AddOutParameter(dbCommand, "pon_error_no", DbType.Decimal, 10)
db.AddOutParameter(dbCommand, "pov_error_msg", DbType.String, 400)
db.AddOutParameter(dbCommand, "pov_applist", DbType.String, 100)
db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand)
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle error codes in the range -20000 to -20999 are user-defined. Therefore nobody on this forum can help you with this error, since it was raised programmatically by custom code within the stored proc you are calling. You will have to dig into the code of the procedure and find out what that error code means by reading the code.